# Laptop crashes when webcam is on

Tags: google-chrome, crash, bsod, webcam

Sequence of actions that cause BSOD:
1. Turn on webcam photo capture in browser (tried in chrome)
2. close the tab while photo capture is still on
3. Receive a BSOD "APC Index Mismatch"

This is confirmed by using facebook "take photo" thing, and also by using this page: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

bsod only happens if I clicked "accept"
bsod doesn't happen when using skype.
What are possible causes of this? Flash plugin? Hard drive? Ram?

Comment: we need more information. what make and model laptop is this? what are its specs?

Comment: upload the dumps so that we can look at them with WinDbg.